# Scipy Optimisation with Quadrature

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to solve an optimisation, but instead of a function, I am optimising over the parameters of a functional.

Here is an example

```
def Q(a,b,c):
    d = integrate.quad(lambda x: (a*x**2+b*x+c), 0, 1)
    return d
def u(a,b,c):
    e = a+b+c
    return e
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
     'fun' : lambda u: np.array([u - 1]),}),
f = lambda x: Q(x[0],x[1],x[2])
res = minimize(Q, args=(3,), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

I want to minimize the functional Integral Q, given the constraint on the parameters. Ideally I could make the constraint an integral as well. I've not included this here because I want to start off simple.

The error I get is

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-158-cdbd019dd886>         
in <module>() 8 'fun' : lambda u: np.array([u - 1]),}), 9 f = lambda x:   
Q(x[0],x[1],x[2]) ---> 10 res = minimize(Q, args=(3,), method='SLSQP', 
constraints=cons) TypeError: minimize() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)
```

It should be stated that I'm not bothered about what kind of code or edits I use to get this to work! just want it to work.

Comment: Your question should include mention of a specific problem that you are experiencing. What is it, please?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-cdbd019dd886> in <module>()
      8          'fun' : lambda u: np.array([u - 1]),}),
      9 f = lambda x: Q(x[0],x[1],x[2])
---> 10 res = minimize(Q, args=(3,), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)

TypeError: minimize() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: This should go in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Start with basics:

- `minimize` requires an initial guess, x0.
- the parameter that `minimize` works with is a single vector, not three variables like a,b,c.
- `quad` returns a tuple of two numbers, in which the 0th one is the integral and the other is the error.
- `args` means additional (fixed) parameters to supply to the objective function, not the number of its arguments.
- your constraint function just didn't make a lot of sense.

When those issues are addressed, the code begins to look less like [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) that it is now.

```
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def Q(u):
    a, b, c = u
    d = integrate.quad(lambda x: (a*x**2+b*x+c), 0, 1)
    return d[0]
cons = ({'type': 'eq',
     'fun' : lambda u: u[0]+u[1]+u[2]-1})

res = minimize(Q, x0 = (1, 2, 3), method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering how I could extend this to something more useful, for example the case where the constraints are themselves integrals evaluated using quaderature. such as

Comment: the error I get is 

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: The code is  `def s(x,a,b,c,d):`
    `v = [1, x, x**2, x**3]`
    `alpha = [a, b, c, d]
    q = np.inner(v,alpha)
    return -q*np.exp(-q)
def p(x,a,b,c,d):
    v = [1, x, x**2, x**3]
    alpha = [a, b, c, d]
    q = np.inner(v,alpha)
    return np.exp(-q)`

Comment: `def Q(u):
    a, b, c, d = u
    d = integrate.quad(lambda x: s(x,a,b,c,d), 0, 1)
    return d[0]
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda x: p(x,a,b,c,d), 0, 1)-1},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda x: (p(x,a,b,c,d)*x), 0, 1)-0.8},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda x: (p(x,a,b,c,d)*x**2), 0, 1)-0.6},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda x: (p(x,a,b,c,d)*x**3), 0, 1)-0.3})
res = minimize(Q, x0 = (0, 0, 0, 0), method='BFGS', constraints=cons)
print(res)`

Comment: If you have another question, ask another one. Here I'll just repeat that __`quad` returns a tuple__ (integral, error), so you should have `quad(...)[0]` if you only want the integral.